# HTML Menu Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu in an html page with the following code:

```
<header>
     <div class="sticky-nav">
        <a id="mobile-nav" class="menu-nav" href="#menu-nav"></a>

        <nav id="menu">
        <ul id="menu-nav">
            <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="clubs.html">Clubs</a></li>
            <li><a href="campaigns.html">Campaigns</a></li>
            <li><a href="movement.html">Movement</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/OfficialAevidum/videos">Videos</a></li>
            <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="the_talk.html">The Talk</a></li>
            <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://aevidum.logoshop.com/">Store</a></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>

    </div>
</header>
```

There is a problem with the menu where when I have this one JQuery file linked to the html page the menu doesn't work and i can click the mobile menu but I can't click the links. But when I don't have it linked i can click the links but then the mobile menu doesn't work.

Here is my JQuery Code for that file:

```
(function() {

(function(root, factory) {
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
  return define(['jquery', 'waypoints'], factory);
} else {
  return factory(root.jQuery);
}
})(this, function($) {
var defaults, wrap;
defaults = {
  wrapper: '<div class="sticky-wrapper" />',
  stuckClass: 'stuck'
};
wrap = function($elements, options) {
  $elements.wrap(options.wrapper);
  $elements.each(function() {
    var $this;
    $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().height($this.outerHeight());
    return true;
  });
  return $elements.parent();
};
return $.waypoints('extendFn', 'sticky', function(options) {
  var $wrap, originalHandler;
  options = $.extend({}, $.fn.waypoint.defaults, defaults, options);
  $wrap = wrap(this, options);
  originalHandler = options.handler;
  options.handler = function(direction) {
    var $sticky, shouldBeStuck;
    $sticky = $(this).children(':first');
    shouldBeStuck = direction === 'down' || direction === 'right';
    $sticky.toggleClass(options.stuckClass, shouldBeStuck);
    if (originalHandler != null) {
      return originalHandler.call(this, direction);
    }
  };
  $wrap.waypoint(options);
  return this;
 });
 });

 }).call(this);
```

Finally, the directory I'm working off of is as follows: http://aevidum.com/brushed

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to do some debugging on this. Look in your browser developer tools so you know what question to ask.

Comment: may be the file you are adding is conflicting.try with jquery noConflict like this:$.noConflict();